# How to find a minimal set of routes to visit all nodes in a graph from a given set of routes?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

From a given graph, not necessarily connected, and a set of paths, where each path visit a set of nodes in the graph. And the nodes visited by two different paths may or may not be exclusive.

With that information is there a way to find the minimun number of paths needed to visit all the nodes in the graph?
Is there some well defined problem in graph theory, like the travel salesman, that covers this problem?, if there is would you please be so kind to tell me which is its name so i can look for an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to minimum set cover and is known to be NP-complete problem. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Consider every path of those you are interested in as a subset of the set of all graph vertices and you get the same problem.

Comment: Right, but you mean NP-**hard**, and to show the equivalence you have to do the reduction the other way: given any minimum set cover problem, you can convert this to an equivalent instance of the OP's problem by making a complete graph having the set of all elements as vertices.  Then each covering subset can be converted to a path by ordering its vertices arbitrarily; this always forms a path because the graph is complete.

Comment: @j_random_hacker in this particular problem statement I considered the two-way equivalence too obvious to be too descriptive. Anyway, thanks for the addition!

Comment: OK, but please edit "NP" to "NP-hard" (or even better, "NP-complete").  Minimum set cover is an NP problem, but so is adding two numbers!